# Objective C Regex Line starts with number

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I need a regex string for finding a line starting with a number. My future intention is to find an ordered list. So if you also know how to do that I would appreciate it. But I can't figure out how to find a line that starts with a number.

Here is what I have so far.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(^[0-9].*)" options:0 error:nil];
```

Example:

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. How's it going eh?
4. Another example string
```

It should match all of these strings

Comment: Try `@"(?m)^[0-9].*"`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your regular expression as such - it matches the first line in its input which starts with a digit. You need to explain why it doesn't do what you want, e.g. show your use of the regular expression, the string you are operating on, what it gives you, and what you want it to give you. With that information someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @Ven: Did my suggestion work?

Comment: Yes it did thank you! Do you want to type it as an answer so I can mark it the answer.

Comment: @Ven: I added an answer, please next time add user name tag when writing a comment :) I was lucky I did not shut this page on my home computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match multiline input, you need to specify the `(?m)` multiline modifier. Available ones are listed in [*NSRegularExpression Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/):

> **(?ismwx-ismwx:...)**
>   Flag settings. Evaluate the parenthesized expression with the specified flags enabled or -disabled. The flags are defined in Flag Options.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?m)^[0-9].*" options:0 error:nil];
                                                                                 ^^^^
```

This mode makes `^` and `$` match at the start and end of a *line*, not the whole string.

Also note that using a capturing group around the whole pattern is not efficient, as the whole match is always captured into Group 1 (e.g. `[match rangeAtIndex:0];`). Thus, I removed the capturing group (the parentheses).